# Using Angular HttpClient inside for loop

Tags: angular, httpclient

I have some issues with Angular's HttpClient:

So, the app logic looks like:
**component.ts:**

I need to call *createNewVideoUploadId()* from service to get ID for upload video. Than I need to send file to Service Method:

```
uploadVideoToApi() {
    this.lessonService.createNewVideoUploadId()
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.lessonService.uploadNewVideo(this.videoToUpload, res['X-Upload-File-ID'])
        })
}
```

**lessonService** look like:

```
createNewVideoUploadId() {
    return this.http.get<string>(`${environment.apiUrl}/upload/id`)
}
```

**uploadNewVideo:**

```
uploadNewVideo(video: File, id: string) {

    const chunkSize = 10 * 1024 ** 2;
    const count = Math.ceil(video.size / chunkSize);

    let calls = []

    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        let chunk = video.slice(i * chunkSize, (i + 1) * chunkSize);

        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', chunk);
        fd.append('file_name', video.name);
        fd.append('file_size', video.size.toString());
        fd.append('chunk_size', chunkSize.toString());
        fd.append('chunk_number', i.toString());
        fd.append('chunks_count', count.toString());

        return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/upload/${id}`, fd)
    }
} // uploadNewVideo()
```

So, **for** loop is stopping in first iteration because of *return*

I need to execute each for loop iteration one by one from component.ts

So, I need to subscribe to uploadNewVideo, and get responses. But I cant return anything from cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could RxJS `forkJoin()` method. Try the following

```js
uploadNewVideo(video: File, id: string) {
  const chunkSize = 10 * 1024 ** 2;
  const count = Math.ceil(video.size / chunkSize);
  let calls = []

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let chunk = video.slice(i * chunkSize, (i + 1) * chunkSize);

    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', chunk);
    fd.append('file_name', video.name);
    fd.append('file_size', video.size.toString());
    fd.append('chunk_size', chunkSize.toString());
    fd.append('chunk_number', i.toString());
    fd.append('chunks_count', count.toString());

    calls.push(this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/upload/${id}`, fd).pipe(retry(3)))   // <-- retry 3x in case of error
  }

  return forkJoin(calls);     // <-- use `forkJoin` here
}
```

Now you could subscribe to the function to trigger the calls

```js
uploadVideoToApi() {
  this.lessonService.createNewVideoUploadId().pipe(
    switchMap(res => this.lessonService.uploadNewVideo(this.videoToUpload, res['X-Upload-File-ID'])),
    catchError(error => of(error))
  ).subscribe(
    response => {
      // handle response
    },
    error => {
      // handle error
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but forkJoin returns each value after for cycle will finish? I need to handle every request and if chunk will lost, resend it.

Comment: `forkJoin` processes each request and will emit value only when all the observables are complete. If you need to resend the request in case of failure, you could pipe in `retry` operator for each HTTP POST request. You could also use `retryWhen` if appropriate. I've modified the answer to retry thrice if the POST request fails.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the http-post streams in an array and concat thoose:

```
uploadNewVideo(video: File, id: string) {

    const chunkSize = 10 * 1024 ** 2;
    const count = Math.ceil(video.size / chunkSize);

    let calls = []
    let httpCalls = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        let chunk = video.slice(i * chunkSize, (i + 1) * chunkSize);

        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', chunk);
        fd.append('file_name', video.name);
        fd.append('file_size', video.size.toString());
        fd.append('chunk_size', chunkSize.toString());
        fd.append('chunk_number', i.toString());
        fd.append('chunks_count', count.toString());

        httpCalls.push(this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/upload/${id}`, fd));
    }

    return concat(httpCalls)
}
```